# Anchor needs twice click to perform action in js

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am calling tab change event on anchor tag click.on first time page load its need twice click to perform that action.After moving to next tab and back then the same function work with one click.I tried different methods but didn't work.My code is below :Html Link

```
<a class="btn btn-default-o pull-right btn-sm" id="checkpname">Next »</a>
```

```js
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#checkpname").click(function() {
        if (jQuery('#name').val() == '') {
            alert("Please select Product name First.")
            jQuery('#name').focus();
            jQuery('#name').css('border', '1px solid red');
        } 
        else { 
            changetab('step2');
        }
    });

    function changetab(hrf){
        jQuery('a.btn').each(function () {
        jQuery(this).click(function () {
            //var thisid = $('#sell .tab-pane.active').attr('id');
            jQuery('.wizard a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass('current');
            jQuery('.wizard a[href="#' + hrf + '"]').click();
        });
    });
}
```

Changing tab is done on clicking twice on link.while once moved to next tab then it did same work on one click which is right way to do it.May be someone can help me

Comment: You are nesting handlers, you shouldn't

Comment: @A.Wolff Means ? Did get you

Comment: The first time you click on anchor, you are binding a second click (calling changetab function). Only the second time you click, the new click handler is called. Sounds like exactly behaviour you are facing

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is due to the way you're binding your change listener/function after you click the link the first time, so you have to click it again to trigger your new click bind (and incidentally, you're also adding another new click bind when you click it the second time).

In your code example you call the function `changetag`, which binds a new click listener onto the `a` tag. Removing the second click bind `jQuery(this).click(function () {` and initiating the click immediately should make it work.

Ex:

```
jQuery(document).ready(function() {
    jQuery("#checkpname").click(function() {
        if (jQuery('#name').val() == '') {
            alert("Please select Product name First.")
            jQuery('#name').focus();
            jQuery('#name').css('border', '1px solid red');
        } 
        else { 
            changetab('step2');
        }
    });

    function changetab(hrf){
        jQuery('a.btn').each(function () {
            //var thisid = $('#sell .tab-pane.active').attr('id');
            jQuery('.wizard a[data-toggle="tab"]').removeClass('current');
            jQuery('.wizard a[href="#' + hrf + '"]').click();
        });
    }
});
```

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you right, you want to click only once to make it work?

Check out this fiddle I made based on your code and let me know if I understood you right ^^

http://jsfiddle.net/wge1e1jL/

```
$("#checkpname").click(function () {

if ($("#name").val() === '') {
    alert("Please select Product name First.");
    $('#name').focus();
    $('#name').css('border', '1px solid red');
} else {
    changetab('step2');
}
});

function changetab(hrf) {
alert('function executed');
$('a.btn').each(function () {
 //   $('this').click(function () {
        alert('second click executed');
        $('.wizard a[data - toggle = "tab"]').removeClass('current');
        $('.wizard a[href = "#' + hrf + '"]').click();
  //     });
   });
}
```